# run the java class from war file in tomcat server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, webserver

i have uploaded one war file in remote tomcat server.here i have to unzip the war file.here i have to run the **Demo** java class on my browser.how can i do????

this is the saved path of Demo.java:

**/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/Example/WEB-INF/classes/com/testprops/ws**

Here i have to run these means URL http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/Example/ means am getting these page successfully.please check this:http://screencast.com/t/DKZW1t9Z1

This is my Demo.java:

```
 public class Demo {
 public String customerData(){
 String customerInfo = "";
 int a=10;
 customerInfo = customerInfo + a;
  try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/android","androiduser","AN124@7#7");
  //Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
   PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers");
   ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
   while(result.next()){
   customerInfo = customerInfo + a + "&" + result.getString("login") + "&" + result.getString("password") + "&"+result.getString("firstname") + "&"+result.getString("email");
   //Here "&"s are added to the return string. This is help to split the string in Android application
    }
      }
    catch(Exception exc){
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
     }  
    return customerInfo;
    }
    }
```

How can i run the Demo.java class on my browser.please help me.

Comment: What does your `Demo.java` look like? Is it a servlet? Do you know how the servlet container works?

Comment: @peter:this is mysql connection with jdbc

Comment: @mwangi: this is mysql connection with jdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you need to write a servlet that runs the code. Basically when you give a request to the above given link, then it calls `Demo.java` class and the output is given.

It is recommended to please first learn a bit basics about servlets. That should help.

So have a simple servlet like

```
public void doGet(HttpServeletRequest r, HttpServletResponse s){
 Demo demo = new Demo();
 demo.run();//your Demo.java is invalid as all that try catch code needs to be inside a method
 }
```

Comment: this is mysql connection with jdbc.

Comment: I am sorry but please learn basics of servlet. It is just not code. you will have to update teh web.xml file and make a servlet. A google search on hello world Servlet should do wonders :)